# Selecting dataframe column that is a mix of string and number in groupby operation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

How do I select the column name in the groupby operation since the column name has integers mixed with string. I cannot replace the name since I need to keep track.

```
import pandas as pd

Signal_val = {'Signal-230_115':[20, 7, 8, 17, 19, 19,7,17,17,17], 'above': [True,False,False,True,True,True,False,True,True,True]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = Signal_val)

groups = df.groupby(['above']).Signal-230_115.size()
```

I am getting invalid syntax error in this case. Is there a way I can select the specified signal column in the groupby operation without explicitly mentioning the Signal name?

Comment: `df.groupby(['above'])['Signal-230_115'].size()`

Comment: Any way to select the specified Signal-230_115 column without explicitly putting its name?

Comment: Sure, `df.groupby(['above'])[df.columns[0]].size()` You can replace the zero with the index of the column you want to use.